# Printing together multiple submits from the same text box

Tags: php, html, forms, input, output

I have a simple task and I got really annoyed for not making it work.
I have a text box and a submit button, and my goal is to print everything that is submitted in a single line.

Fruit: _________ SUBMIT_BUTTON (Buy)

List: ..

So when I submit an apple i get

```
List: apple
```

Then banana

```
List: apple banana
```

You get the idea.

Well my idea is to add newly submitted string to a variable and print it out.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="">
    Fruit:
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Buy" />
  </form>

<?php
$fruit = '';
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
  $fruit = $fruit . ' ' . $_POST['text'];
  echo 'List: ', $fruit;
}
?>
</body>
<html>
```

But I only get the last submitted word. Seems like every time i hit 'Buy' $fruit = ''; executes.

Comment: The problem I noticed is that you kept on on resetting your fruit variable to blank on each page load...  $fruit='';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want the values to persist, you could utilize sessions and create a container which will hold the values submitted. Rough example:

```
<?php

session_start();
// initializations
if(!isset($_SESSION['fruits'])) {
    $_SESSION['fruits'] = array();
}


if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
    $_SESSION['fruits'][] = $_POST['text']; // push the submitted value inside
    echo implode(' ', $_SESSION['fruits']); // join all the values inside it and print it
}
?>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        Fruit:
        <input type="text" name="text" />
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Buy" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Session does it. Thanks a lot.